# Vertical div float on left side middle of a page

Tags: html, css

How can I make a div float left side of a full page and always be in a vertical middle left side?

My html code is simple:

```
<body>
  <div class="num_book">  
    <img src="imgs\PhoneDir.png" alt="phone dir" height="142.2" width="45.6">
  </div>
</body>
```

My css is so far:

```
.num_book {
   float: left; 
}
```

I've tried in my css: position, margin, padding, display, vertical-align with no luck,
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way, using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.wrapper {
    /* vertical bar on left side */
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; 

    /* align items inside vertically centered */
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
.centered {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="centered">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

The `.wrapper` is a fixed ([see `position`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)) vertical bar on the left side, and `.centered` inside is aligned vertically to the center (see `display: flex` and [`align-items`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box"></div>

<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2017, [use a flexbox](https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center-flexbox).

```
.container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[MDN has a good example of this too.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Holy_Grail_Layout_example)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set top to 50%, position absolute.

```
<style>
    .num_book {
       float: left; 
       top:50%;
       position:absolute;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
      <div class="num_book">  
        <img src="imgs\PhoneDir.png" alt="phone dir" height="64" width="64">
      </div>
    </body>
```